# Why is only static_cast able to return new object of requested type?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, reinterpret-cast, static-cast, const-cast

Among static_cast,  dynamic_cast,  reinterpret_cast and  const_cast, only static_cast is able to return an object of desirable type, whereas the other type can return only pointer or reference to representation. Why is it so?

Examples:

```
int y = 3;
double z = reinterpret_cast<double> (y);//error
double z = reinterpret_cast<double&> (y);//ok
double z = static_cast<double> (y);//but this is ok!!!

const int y = 3;
int z = const_cast<int> (y);//error
int z = const_cast<int&> (y);//ok
```

and for dynamic_cast:

```
using namespace std;

class Gun
{
public:
    virtual void shoot(){
        cout << "BANG!\n";
    }
};

class MachineGun : public Gun{
public:
    void shoot() override{
        cout <<"3X-BANG\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Gun gun;
    MachineGun tt;
    Gun* gunp = &gun;
    Gun* gunp1 = &tt;

    Gun* newGun = dynamic_cast<Gun*>(gunp1);//ok
    Gun newGun1 = dynamic_cast<Gun>(tt);//error
}
```

Comment: First of all, these conversions are not library functions but keywords in the language itself. So no `std` namespace prefix. Secondly, `reinterpret_cast` can cast almost anything to almost anything, doesn't have to be pointers or references.

Comment: `static_cast` is performed on compilation, so it's not as safe as `dynamic_cast`. In other words, `static_cast` takes your word and returns the type that you wanted without checks.

Comment: As mentioned by others, while e.g. `dynamic_cast` us almost always used with references or pointer (as it's almost only used for polymorphic down-/up-casting) it can also be used for other conversions. Same with `const_cast`, it can be used to cast between non-const objects or values to const objects or values. Pointers or references not needed.

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible example to your code, what you want to work, and what does not work? Your claims about these keywords seem sweeping, incorrect and confused.

Comment: The close reason given obviously does not apply. This is a fair question to ask. A good answer would provide insight into the language. Vote to reopen.

Comment: `std::bit_cast` can also return objects

Comment: @ÖöTiib , done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making attempt to explain based on example, as addition to other answer that did explain nature of casts.

```
int y = 3;
double z = reinterpret_cast<double> (y);//error
```

This is not one of 11 allowed casts with [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). Also [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) can't cast it on most platforms as the `int` typically does not have enough bits for `double`. So it is unsure what you wanted to achieve.

```
double z = reinterpret_cast<double&> (y);//ok
```

This is present in list of valid `reinterpret_cast` but likely causes undefined behaviour for same reason why `std::bit_cast` refuses. In typical implementation your `z` is bigger than `y` and so takes bits beyond memory location of `y`. In such places prefer `std::bit_cast` that does not compile to undefined behaviour but refuses to compile.

```
double z = static_cast<double> (y);//but this is ok!!!
```

But that is fully valid. It is effectively same as

```
double z = y;
```

Compilers do not even warn about the latter. However when the value range of `y` does not fully fit to `z` then it is not clear if it was intentional. On such cases it is better to use former to indicate intent.

```
const int y = 3;
int z = const_cast<int> (y);//error
```

That is good. Absurd [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) does not compile! Or how does the effect that you tried to achieve differ from lot more readable

```
int z = y;
```

I would write that. Please describe the situation where you would write former.

```
int z = const_cast<int&> (y);//ok
```

Works, but is similarly unneeded and confusing like previous. I would only use `const_cast` for situations like that:

```
int x;
const int& y = x;
int& z = const_cast<int&> (y);
z = 42;
```

Here I know that thing referred by reference to const `y` is really not const originally and so it is not undefined behaviour to modify it to `42`.

About [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) your example does not make sense at all what it wants to do:

```
Gun newGun1 = dynamic_cast<Gun>(tt);//error
```

It could be perhaps trying to do something like that:

```
Gun newGun1 = tt;
```

That compiles. However that results with `newGun1` initialised with sliced out `Gun` base sub-object of `MachineGun tt` and that is often programming error. What you tried to achieve with cast remains totally dark however.

Comment: Thanks for thorough consideration. I confirm that many of written in question is nonsense. Like truncating to Base might be done just by assignment. However I wanted to see strict explanation of the restrictions in the very language, otherwise it could have been only my vague guesses.

Answer (score 5):

> Only static_cast is able to return an object of desirable type

This is incorrect. All casts return an object when the cast target is an object type.

That said:

- const_cast target can only be a reference, pointer to object or pointer to member. This is because other types aren't compound types whose "inner" type's cv-qualifiers could be modified.
- dynamic_cast target can only be a reference or a pointer to object. You cannot have polymorphism without indirection. References and pointers are the forms of indirection that exist in C++.

Comment: "All casts return an object when the cast target is an object type" seems to be flatly contradicted by your later "const_cast target can only be a reference, pointer to object or pointer to member" and "dynamic_cast target can only be a reference or a pointer to object".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: Am I missing something? Pointers and references in this context are opposed to objects, so if the two casts can only operate on those (your second claims) they can **never** return objects (your first claim). To me, that is a contradiction.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Pointers (as well as pointers to members) are objects.

Comment: @eeroika I take that as a deliberate misunderstanding of what the OP meant.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica OP has misunderstood what an object is in C++. It's important for the reader to understand what it means. You'll find that there is a second part in my answer the question that OP tried to ask.

Comment: If you find the OP is using terminology incorrectly you should point that out.

Comment: I've added examples to the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a short (memorable) answer is that `static_cast` can take a type with no reference (and no pointer) because it is the only cast that can invoke a constructor of the target type.

Please correct me if I am wrong.